# Select macro between two words in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Can somebody please help me in this [excel](/questions/tagged/excel). I need to select between 2 words what I define before and delete it..

For example:

> http:/ertwertw4r!%!+53445433333/cat.jpgThere is a dog

I need to select the text from `http:` till the `.jpg` and delete it or replace it for ``. As I only need the *There is a dog* portion

This was successful in [word](/questions/tagged/word)

```
Sub Macro () 
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting 
 With Selection.Find 
  .Text = "http:" 
  .Replacement.Text = "" 
  .Forward = True 
  .Wrap = wdFindContinue 
 End With 
Selection.Find.Execute 
Selection.Extend 
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting 
 With Selection.Find 
  .Text = ".jpg" 
  .Replacement.Text = "" 
  .Forward = True .Wrap = wdFindContinue 
 End With 
Selection.Find.Execute 
End Sub
```

Regards

Comment: Will this address will always have an `http:` and a `.jpg`?

Comment: Yepp, Always begins with http: and always ends with .jpg...Only the text between is always different...

Comment: does your input text contain ONE link? eg: `http://aaa.jpgTitle` or are there multiple `http:/aaa.jpgTitle1http:/bbb.jpgTitle2`?

Answer (score 3):

Recording a macro that replaces "http:*.jpg" with "" I get:

```
 Selection.Replace What:="http:*.jpg", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
```

"http:*.jpg" means anything that starts with "http:" and ends with ".jpg". Any text before or after is left in place.

Answer (score 1):

If your string will always have `.jpg`, then you can just use a regular excel formula (no VBA):

```
=RIGHT(A1,
    LEN(A1)-(FIND(".jpg",A1)+3)
)
```

Comment: I dont need only find it, its easy...I need to select this all...From http: until .jpg and need to clear all this...I need only the text what are after this all...

Comment: http:/ertwertw4r!%!+53445433333/cat.jpgThere is a dog **********
http:/ertwee65e464e65e5433333/cat.jpgHere we are **********http:/ertwertw4rshkjdtzijtzddjdtzjd3333/cat1.jpgThis need too*************************
All i need only the words after .jpg ... Others must be erase...

Comment: Try the code before you shoot it down. It searches for the last instance of ".jpg" and returns the text after it.

Comment: @Pater, that is exactly what this does.  It gives you all the text after `.jpg`